# Android OpenGL es "glDrawTexfOES" draws upside down

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawing, 2d

I'm using OpenGL for Android to draw my 2D images.

Whenever I draw something using the code:

```
    gl.glViewport(aspectRatioOffset, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();

    GLU.gluOrtho2D(gl, aspectRatioOffset, screenWidth + aspectRatioOffset,screenHeight, 0);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, myScene.neededGraphics.get(ID).get(animationID).get(animationIndex));

    crop[0] = 0;
    crop[1] = 0;
    crop[2] = width;
    crop[3] = height;
    ((GL11Ext)gl).glDrawTexfOES(x, y, z, width, height)
```

I get an upside down result. I'v seen people solve this through doing:

```
    crop[0] = 0;
    crop[1] = height;
    crop[2] = width;
    crop[3] = -height;
```

This does however hurt the logic in my application, so I would like the result to not be flipped upside down. Does anyone know why it happen, and any way of avoiding or solving it?

Edit: I found a solutions, though I don't know if it is a good one:

```
    int[] crop = new int[4];
    crop[0] = 0;
    crop[1] = imageDimension[ID][1];
    crop[2] = imageDimension[ID][0];
    crop[3] = -imageDimension[ID][1];

    ((GL11)gl).glTexParameteriv(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_CROP_RECT_OES, crop, 0);
    ((GL11Ext)gl).glDrawTexfOES(x, ScreenHeight - y - height, 0, width, height);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define upside down. OpenGL defines (0, 0) to be in the lower left of the display with y going upward. `glDrawTexOES` is explicitly defined to work in window coordinates so there's no matrix stack in between even in ES 1.0. If you've set up your projection or modelview matrices to flip coordinates to whatever OpenGL considers upside down then that's not going to have any effect during a call to `glDrawTexOES`.

What generally happens is that people implicitly flip their graphics when loading them (because they ignore OpenGL's placement of the origin), causing them to appear upside down when using `glDrawTexOES`. The correct solution is that if you don't want to have to flip coordinates manually later on then don't implicitly flip them when loading your images and/or when setting up your matrix stacks.

Comment: I'm very new to OpenGL, and have just started to try and convert my project which used the Canvas into using something more efficient. It's very possible that I could have gotten something wrong before this step, I'll look closer at it.

Comment: I think it's more likely that you've done nothing wrong other than tried to bolt a texture loading system that assumes you prefer to think of stored textures as having the origin at the top left and to fix texture coordinates elsewhere to `glDrawTexOES` which, unlike pretty much the entire rest of the API, takes direct window coordinates so you don't get a chance to flip coordinates invisibly.

Comment: If I understood it right, my code should already have flipped the images, but I don't want to do that since glDrawTexOES has the same coordinate system as the Canvas?